# Where do I store cross platform C++ app storage?

Tags: c++, installation, operating-system, cross-platform

I want to store gigabytes of media locally - and have them automatically removed when the app is uninstalled. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006205/appdata-similar-for-all-os-c), but it requires the qt library, and only stores app settings.

I'm guessing there's a convention followed across Windows, Mac and Linux. Are there any `std` helpers - or the like - for storing app data, cross-platform.

If not, is there a convention for the paths would I need to store these in, on each platform? I plan on creating an installer for each operating system, so it would be useful to know these paths so I can install my other data here.

Comment: No, there is nothing in the C++ library for this.

Comment: It's more complex for Linux. You have different package managers like rpm, dnf, yum, apt, dpkg, pacman, yast, apm and many more. In addition there are crosslinux package managers like snap, flatpak and appimage. Even folder structure can be different on different distros even thought there is a [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Comment: You have two cross-platform problems: (1) identifying the right place to store a big chunk of app data, and (2) how to hook the uninstall process to clean it up. Both of these will be system-specific. Frameworks like Qt have done the leg work to figure out what the right answer for each system is and do that when you call their generic interface. Qt also has an installer system, and CMake's CPack may help there too, but I've not tried them for your specific use case. So you can either adopt some helpers that help with such problems or roll your own, which will be tricky to test everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store gigabytes of media locally - and have them automatically removed when the app is uninstalled.

The average but skilled user is capable of copying the media elsewhere and would backup his disk regularly.

However, most C++ programs have a `main` accepting program arguments, and you could *conventionally* provide program arguments to remove the data. Be sure to properly document your design.

See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065). On Unix or POSIX systems (Linux, MacOSX, FreeBSD....), you might accept a `--clean-all-the-mess` program option.

> I'm guessing there's a convention followed across Windows, Mac and Linux.

As far as I know, **this guess is wrong.** (things are *much* more complex)

More generally, read about [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager). There are many of them. See [guix](https://guix.gnu.org/) for an interesting example. [Debian](https://debian.org/) and [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)) have different ones. Look into [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) and [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf).

You could want to use a database, perhaps [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/).

On Linux, see also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and more about [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

On Windows, read about the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

> Is there a convention for the paths would I need to store these

Linux has [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) but some Linux distributions (including Android) don't follow that.

My recommendation: **study the C++ code of some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software** close to your goals. You could find some of them on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) or [SoftwareHeritage](https://www.softwareheritage.org/). See also [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/).

Answer (score -1):

"Application Uninstall" event is visible to the OS, so your best bet is on finding some OS-specific hooks to register your call-backs to remove your local files yourself.

**EDIT:**
C++ STL is a piece of code (library) to write applications that run on top of some OS, so STL is not the place to look for application install/uninstall events, that are OS-level events. But nothing prevents you from writing an Uninstaller application for any OS. The question is who or how and when it will be executed.

Comment: Where is this Application Uninstall event in Linux?

Comment: I'm not a linux programmer, but if you're concerned about linux, imho it's managing all the apps as packages via its package-managers. So to provide such a functionality for your app you need to have your app listed by those package-managers. How? I have no idea, but try googling and reading about PPA (Personal Package Archive).

Comment: So this is a comment but not an answer

Comment: @ThomasSablik, My answer is above comments.

Comment: _"Application Uninstall event is visible to the OS"_ is not true for all Linux distros. There are enough Linux distros without package manager.

Comment: Visible doesn't mean that they necessarily do something with it. I was justifying the wrong direction of thoughts that OP was moving along.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, besides visibility, the original question was not particularly about linux OS. My comment about package-managers in linux was (indeed a comment as you noticed) a reply to your comment.

Comment: You don't even address _"Where do I store cross platform C++ app storage?"_

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I've explained the infeasibility of the question, why should I have even tried to answer it afterwards?

Comment: You have a usual filesystem hierarchy for the three mentioned OS (Windows, Linux, Mac). You could answer _"If not, is there a convention for the paths would I need to store these in, on each platform?"_

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I don't think that any of those 3 OS have a "usual filesystem", in sense that each of those is unique and is quite different from each other. Yes, I could answer to many other questions as well, but I chose not to.

Comment: That is what I meant with _"So this is a comment but not an answer"_. You didn't answer this question but you gave a helpful comment.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I already got your point that you dislike my answer, but I'm cool with it. Thank you.